# set sankey flow.fill to last node

Tags: r, ggplot2

In my example sankey diagram, the flow.fill and flow.color are set by the previous node (e.g., all "yellow" flows at time_0 have yellow fill). I would like to color the flows by the final node. For instance, all flows going into "yellow" at time_1 (yellow-yellow, red-yellow) have yellow fill instead of what you see below (red-yellow is red).

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggsankey)

set.seed(2)

# standard sankey

df <- tibble(
  id = seq(1:22168),
  time_0 = c(rep("red", 13309), rep("yellow", 8699), rep("green", 160)),
  time_1 = c(rep("red", 1110), rep("yellow", 3771), rep("green", 8428),
             rep("red", 321), rep("yellow", 1940), rep("green", 6438),
             rep("red", 4), rep("yellow", 26), rep("green", 130))
) %>%
  {. ->> df2} %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("time"), factor,
                levels = c("green", "yellow", "red")))



df_sankey <- df %>%
  ggsankey::make_long(time_0, time_1)

df_sankey_t <- df_sankey %>%
  dplyr::group_by(x, node)%>%
  tally()

df_sankey <- df_sankey %>%
  left_join(df_sankey_t, by = c("x", "node"))


ggplot(df_sankey,
             aes(x = x, next_x = next_x,
                 node = node, next_node = next_node,
                 fill = factor(node),
                 label = paste0(node," n=", n))) +
  geom_sankey(flow.alpha = 0.6, node.color = "gray30") +
  geom_sankey_label(size = 3, color = "white", fill = "gray40") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "red", "yellow")) +
  theme_sankey(base_size = 18) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        plot.title.position = "plot",
        plot.title = element_text(face="bold", size=20),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size=15)) +
  labs(title = "Example sankey diagram",
       subtitle = "Would like to color flow.fill and flow.color to be based on last node",
       x = NULL)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is currently possible - it looks like there's an open GitHub issue with this feature request: https://github.com/davidsjoberg/ggsankey/issues/13

Answer (score 1):

You can get part of the way using `PantaRhei` and all the way with inputs from `grid`

```r
library(PantaRhei)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)


df1 <- tibble(
  id = seq(1:22168),
  time_0 = c(rep("red", 13309), rep("yellow", 8699), rep("green", 160)),
  time_1 = c(rep("red", 1110), rep("yellow", 3771), rep("green", 8428),
             rep("red", 321), rep("yellow", 1940), rep("green", 6438),
             rep("red", 4), rep("yellow", 26), rep("green", 130))
) |> 
  mutate(across(starts_with("time"), factor,
                levels = c("green", "yellow", "red")))

# summarise data for flows
# the heading names are specific to Panta Rhei for processing the data
# Panta Rhei documentation uses the 'substance' variable to name the 'substance' or name
# of the flow, in this case we'll use it to determine the fill. 
# There may be more efficient ways to define unique 'from' and 'to' variables depending on your data.

flows <- 
  df1 |>
  group_by(time_0, time_1) |> 
  summarise(quantity = n(), .groups = "drop") |> 
  mutate(substance = time_1,
         from = case_when(time_0 == "yellow" ~ "B",
                          time_0 == "red" ~ "A",
                          time_0 == "green" ~ "C"),
         to = case_when(time_1 == "yellow" ~ "D",
                        time_1 == "red" ~ "E",
                        time_1 == "green" ~ "F")) 

# build up a nodes data frame
# to set labels and position of nodes

nodes <- 
  data.frame(ID = c(unique(flows$from), unique(flows$to)),
             label = c(unique(flows$from), unique(flows$to)),
             x = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3)),
             y = c("1", "1.25", "1.5", "C", "B", "A"),
             label_pos = rep(c("left", "right"), each = 3))


colors <- tribble(
  ~substance, ~color,
  "yellow",    "yellow",
  "red",    "red",
  "green",    "green"
)


sankey(nodes, flows, colors, legend = FALSE)

# PantaRhei limitations
# Although you could change the colour of the nodes, there does not seem to be a way colour nodes individually
# While individual nodes are labelled I could not find a way to label the node columns (not sure of the correct term).
# Unable to control the formatting for node quantity.
# Not sure how to control the order of the 'to' nodes. 
# As PantaRhei is build from grid you could probably add these features to your model.

# 'grid' based edits noted below:

library(grid)
# functions to inspect the grid tree.
# grid.force()
# grid.ls()
# grid.ls(grobs = FALSE, viewports = TRUE)

# make edits following inspection and a bit of trial and error...
grid.edit("GRID.polygon.38", gp = gpar(fill="red"))
grid.edit("GRID.polygon.33", gp = gpar(fill="yellow"))
grid.edit("GRID.polygon.29", gp = gpar(fill="green"))

grid.edit("GRID.polygon.17", gp = gpar(fill="red"))
grid.edit("GRID.polygon.21", gp = gpar(fill="yellow"))
grid.edit("GRID.polygon.25", gp = gpar(fill="green"))

# Get back to the root viewport
popViewport()

# add labels to node columns

grid.text(label = c("time_0", "time_1"), x = c(0.25, 0.75), y = rep(0.15, 2))

# you could also edit the node labels
# I've just edited one as an example

grid.edit("GRID.text.39", label = "Red")

# There may be more efficient ways to achieve the effect you desire.
# I'm still getting to grips with grid...!
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>